# Name not recognized in method

Tags: c#

In the following example I'm trying to access my list in a method, but the name of the list is not recognized, why?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<DutyDay> tour = new List<DutyDay>();
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 1:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 2:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 3:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 4:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 5:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 6:" });

        listBoxDutyDays.ItemsSource = tour;
    }

    private void DatePicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DutyDay item in tour)  <-- "tour" is not recognized?!
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to make the list public or put it in between other brackets, but the interpreter was not happy about it.

Sorry for the silly question but im still new...

Comment: [variable scope in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your List variable is declared inside the constructor of Window that means it only accessible within that constructor.

So make this variable `tour`  as global then it can be accessed throughout the class.

Like

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    List<DutyDay> tour = new List<DutyDay>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Your other stuff here.
    }

    private void DatePicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DutyDay item in tour)  <-- Now its recognized
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about Local and Global variable [here](https://funprogramming.org/50-What-are-global-and-local-variables.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the quick answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `Tour` an instance member not a local variable, as it will have no scope in the other method

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<DutyDay> tour = new List<DutyDay>();

    ...
```

---

**Further Reading**

[Classes (C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

[Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members)

[Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Comment: Thanks, the `VisualStyleElement.Window` wasn't even necessary just putting the declaration further up did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You Just Need Declare it in global scope to Access it.

try This

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<DutyDay> tour = new List<DutyDay>(); // it is declared as global
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //List<DutyDay> tour = new List<DutyDay>(); It Is declared as local
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 1:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 2:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 3:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 4:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 5:" });
        tour.Add(new DutyDay() { Day = "Day 6:" });

        listBoxDutyDays.ItemsSource = tour;
    }

    private void DatePicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DutyDay item in tour)  <-- "tour" is not recognized?!
        {

        }
    }
}
```